# C# WPF Exception when inserting a record EntryPointNotFoundException

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I've got an WPF application I'm writing, however whilst testing the insert of a record I'm getting the below exception.

The Application is using .NET 4.8, I'm using Entity Framework 5.

The exception I'm getting is:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'ExtentPlaceholderCreator' threw an exception.'

EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'SetClrFeatureSwitchMap' in DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll'.
```

The stack trace is:

```
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.GetPropagatorResultForPrimitiveType(PrimitiveType primitiveType, PropagatorResult& result)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.Visit(EdmMember node)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.CreateEntitySetPlaceholder(EntitySet entitySet)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.CreatePlaceholder(EntitySetBase extent, UpdateTranslator parent)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Visit(DbScanExpression node)
   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbScanExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateExpressionVisitor`1.Visit(DbExpression expression)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Visit(DbProjectExpression node)
   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Propagate(UpdateTranslator parent, EntitySet table, DbQueryCommandTree umView)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.<ProduceDynamicCommands>d__44.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__59`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCommandOrderer..ctor(IEnumerable`1 commands, UpdateTranslator translator)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Desktop.Views.Products.AddTemplates.MobilesAdd.SaveButton_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Tom\source\repos\MyApp\Desktop\Views\Products\AddTemplates\MobilesAdd.xaml.cs:line 59
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Desktop.App.Main()
```

Looking online I can see suggestions that I need a reference in my .config file however I can only see responses for web forms or mvc rather than WPF so not really sure if its the same issue or a different one as my app.config doesn't look like the examples for those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding an Entity Framework update I've updated, that's then advised that there was a decimal record that was out of scope so I've resolved it!